# Crystal Reports Server - get list of currently running reports and their progress

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

Hope it's the right place to ask this question - usually I use SO to ask about programming...

I'm doing a project that involves Crystal Reports Server. From code, I'm able to schedule reports successfully, but when I look at the BI launch pad I don't see the report in My Recently Run Documents (I see failed reports in that list - ones that has wrong database credentials).

When I go to Central Management Console and I find my reports in folders and I go to Properties > History I see the report status as "Running" - and it has been like that for a long while (too long than it should) for 2 different reports I have sent.

- How can I diagnose what the problem is? and why it is stuck? there are no error messages anywhere about it.
- How can I get a full history of all reports in the system (not just one single report at a time)? and how can I see currently running reports?
- How can I stop a running report?

I really hope this is the right place for these kind of questions... if not, would be very happy to get a referral.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How can I get a full history of all reports in the system?*

Open the CMC and then click on the *Instance Manager*. At the bottom of the page, you can filter on the object type and status. That way, you can get a full overview of all running reports on your platform.

*How can I stop a running report?*

If you select a running instance (either in a document's history page or in the Instance Manager), you'll notice that there is no stop button. Instead, you have to *delete* the running instance. It might not stop running immediately though (depending on what it's doing), but it will be removed immediately from the list of instances.

*How can I diagnose what the problem is?*

What I would recommend is to enable tracing on all related servers (thus your job server, processing server, etc) and then retry scheduling the report. This should generate additional logging on the server which you can use to diagnose the issue.

- The trace files have the extension `.glf` (generic log file) and are located in the logging folder on your Crystal Server. Have a look at the command-line property of each of the servers for which you're enabling the tracing, you should find a log folder there somewhere.
- Make sure to turn the tracing off again as soon as you're finished, as tracing will not only create extra strain on your servers (causing the system to slow down), but it will also result in very large log files.
- Before starting with tracing, have a look at the existing log files to see if it doesn't already contain error messages that might help you diagnose the issue. Sort the log files by date, and look at the most recent one for each of the servers involved. If there's nothing in there, start with tracing, but remove the existing `.glf` files to minimise log contamination (some files will be locked, just ignore them).

Comment: Hi, do you know of a way to export the data I find in the Instance screen to excel? thanks.

Comment: There's no option that will allow you to directly export the information. Alternatives are to use the Query builder (http://<BOBJ web server>:<port>/AdminTools or revert to the SDK (REST or Java).